# How to Edit a Database List with Dynamic List ID From PHP using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a list of product items inside a table. Each row has their own edit and delete button. I can do the delete function because it use PHP via url. But the problem on the edit button is that I have a modal div hidden on the page and when user press' the edit button for that row (item), the modal showed up (done) and I want to ajax-ly insert that row data (from db) to the modal form input. And save it with ajax too. I add an ID for each row with format of `id="editProduk-xxx` where xxx is the product ID. And I just need to know how to access that dynamic id using jQuery so I can do some ajax with the modal using the product item (row) as reference.

This is the form:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nama</th>
<th>Jenis Produk</th>
<th>Harga Satuan</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th>Keterangan</th>
<th>Menu</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($list_produk as $key => $value): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $value->nama; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value->jenis_produk; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value->harga; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value->unit; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value->keterangan; ?></td>
<td>
<a id="<?php echo 'editProduk-'.$value->id; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/produk/edit/'.$value->id; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="icon-pencil"></span></a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/produk/hapus/'.$value->id; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="icon-trash"></span></a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And here is what I've tried (but I statically choose the ID: 132, I want dynamic tho)

```js
// example of accessing the row with the productID 132
$('#editProduk-132').on('change', function() {
 $('#modalCustom').show();
 var jumlah = $('#jumlah').val();
 $.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/produk/get'?>"+produk,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success:function(data) {
   // inserting form input with the data from produk/get
   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#productName').val(value.nama);
    $('#productPrice').val(value.harga);
    $('#productType').val(value.jenis_produk);
    $('#productUnit').val(value.unit);
    $('#productInfo').val(value.keterangan);
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Pass product ID i.e. $value->id inside onclick  of span <span class="icon-pencil" onclick="edit_product('<?php echo $value->id;?>')"></span>. Then fire ajax call inside edit_product function.

Comment: @Lalit seems doesn't work, it even doesn't show up my modal

Comment: Have you put this line $('#modalCustom').show(); inside edit_product function?

Comment: @Lalit that's what I did. After $('#modalCustom').show() I put the ajax. So, at least the modal is showing up if the onclick function is succeed

Comment: Should I post dummy code in the answer. So that you can cross check with the code?

Comment: @Lalit https://pastebin.com/FwVWyuV9

Comment: I have added two console logs 1.  console.log("Product ID :"+product_id); and 2. console.log("Nama:"+value.nama); Check if both the console logs prints the expected value in the console. If only first one does it means there is problem with the ajax call. Here is update pastebin https://pastebin.com/uNamyxU8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question assuming you know how to tweak a code till it works for you.

Actually you only need to pass your `ID` to the second form and populate that with your data.

**NOTE:**I'm not much in to `mysqli_*` the code I'm writing is in `PDO`

You create the table with this code right,

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Nama</th>
    <th>Jenis Produk</th>
    <th>Harga Satuan</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Keterangan</th>
    <th>Menu</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($list_produk as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $value->nama; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->jenis_produk; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->harga; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->unit; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->keterangan; ?></td>
    <td>
//Changed to buttons
    <input type="button" class="editProduk" data-id="<?php echo $value->id; ?>">
    <input type ="button" data-id="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" class="delete">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

then you can use jQuery to hand them over to the editing form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".editProduk").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   $('#modalCustom').show().load('index.php?id='+id);
 })
});
```

And when you get the `id` from the jQuery to your processing page you can do something like this. (This part is in `PDO` convert it to `myaqli_*` if you're using it.)

```
include(dbconnect.php);
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["id"]){
 $getDetails = "SELECT * FROM <dbname> WHERE id = :id";
 $getDetailsQ = $dbConnect -> prepare($getDetails);
 $getDetailsQ -> bindPare(':id', $_POST["id"]);
 $getDetailsQ -> execute();
 $rowDetails = $getDetailsQ -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<label for-"name">Name:</label>
<input id="name" value="<?php echo $rowDetails["name"] ?>">
<label for-"product">product:</label>
<input id="product" value="<?php echo $rowDetails["product"] ?>">
.
.
.
.// repeat what ever the details you have in your data base.
</body>
</html>
```

This code is written just to give you an idea what you need to do hope this help you and this is not a copy paste code.

Comment: i understand your code. And I use the part that you use data-id. That's what I'm looking for. It works. The code isn't look like that tho, but it works.

Comment: Glad it helped you I just wrote the entire code as an example in order to show you how to use hand over the data. About the your version against mine is I'm not a `mysqli` person that's why I used `PDO` sorry about that.